# Default value for radio button in AEM 6.2 touch UI

Tags: aem

How to set the Default value for radio button in AEM 6.2 touch UI?

I can set the default value for dropdown using "selected=true", but how to do that for radio button?

Comment: I got this. Added the property "checked(Boolean) true".

Comment: Could you please add your solution to this problem as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

add property
checked {Boolean} = true

Comment: Note that there is currently (6.4) a bug using this method in that if you use this attribute on a button other than the first one in the group, any buttons that come before it within the group will not work correctly.